# Append id to every link generated by joomla

Tags: jquery, url, id

I have an affiliate system that can generate a users affiliate id with a {affiliatecode} if they are logged in and i would like every joomla page to append the users affiliate tracker id to every page so that when they share a link or video ect it will be tracked. Does any one know how to go about this in the core joomla system? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var querystring = 'affiliate=12345';

    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (href)
        {
            href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        }
    });

});
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526172/1362108

Of course changing `affiliate=12345` to whatever your affiliate code is.

Comment: @brigitte18 - I've made a small fix. Please re-try if you've started already

Comment: It works great with strings, is there a way to generate the actual {snippet} like how joomla generates userid on the end of a url i need it to generate the users tracker id. when i replace the string with the curly brace it goes blank

Comment: What does `{snippet}` normally output? Can you give an example?

Comment: i add {affiliate_link} and it generates ?atid=1 for affilitate tracker id 1